# GPU fan making noise intermittenly

Tags: fan, gpu, noise

A few weeks ago I purchased a GT 430 for my desktop and installed it. Upon booting the machine  I heard a fairly loud noise that I figured was a stray cord hitting a spinning fan. I shut down the machine and opened the case and booted it up again. The sound was gone. I did not move any wires and it was obvious that none were in the way of any fans.

I ignored the issue. Today I installed a DVD drive in the same machine. After installing it and booting the machine I heard the same noise. Again I openend the case and booted up. The sound was still there and it was obvious a cable was not causing it. If I moved the case around I could get the sound to go away. I shut it down one more time and could not replicate the sound. I powered off and on 6 or so more times and could not get the noise to reappear.

I assume the GPU's fan is causing this because it did not happen prior to installing it. Seems like this only happens after I've been working in the case... anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Try to change speed of the GPU's fan by the RivaTuner, maybe it'll detect the problem.

Comment: A lot GT430s actually rev too high - the minimum fan speed is at like 65% or something ridiculous.  I've found the only solution is to use Nhibitor to change the firmware and reflash them.  (Unfortunately I don't have one handy so I can't give specifics).

Comment: Maybe you fan's a POS. I bought a new video card about a year back and the fan broke in to being obnoxiously loud like two months in. Since I'd done firmware editing on the card (to make my Mac Pro 'think' it was an Apple card), returning it was also a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I can say is to open the case again and (carefully) put your ear a little bit closer to some components.

If you have not put your graphics card under much stress, this could simply be the normal noise the fan makes when at high speed.

However, without knowing a little more, it could simply be something loose or a ball baring in any other fan moving - personally, I hear that sort of noise coming from PSUs all the time - usually shoving a little bit of paper between them and the case solves it... I thought I would mention this as you said moving the case fixes it - it just reminded me of this.

However, it really could be anything, You can try some cable ties or similar all loose cables, just in case that is what was causing it... but... it really is too hard to help without being there/seeing it. Sorry :(

Comment: Yeah the issue is that the problem seems to vanish when I'm getting ready to investigate it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Problem finally solved. It was a case fan and not the GPU fan after all. Noise always occurred on cold boots and stopping the fan with my finger revealed it was the culprit.